# Loading shapes to a map with DrawingManager Instance

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I want to load shapes to my all_overlays array where I'm storing the shapes
drawn through DrawingManager:

```
    drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
      drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
      drawingControlOptions:{
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT,
        drawingModes:[
                 google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON
            ]
      },
      markerOptions: {
        draggable: true
      },
      polylineOptions: {
        editable: true
      },
      rectangleOptions: polyOptions,
      circleOptions: polyOptions,
      polygonOptions: polyOptions,
      map: map
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function(e) {
        all_overlays.push(e);
        if (e.type != google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER) {
        drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null);
        var newShape = e.overlay;
        newShape.type = e.type;
        google.maps.event.addListener(newShape, 'click', function() {
          setSelection(newShape);
        });
        setSelection(newShape);
      }
    });
```

but the problem is when I push one of this, the type of it seems to be different than the generated by drawing manager:

```
>all_overlays // array have a drawing manager generated object
[Object]
>coords = [ new google.maps.LatLng(-20.2164629885305, -70.1565831899643), new google.maps.LatLng(-20.2166618288932, -70.15673339366913), new google.maps.LatLng(-20.21687325381024, -70.15626400709152), new google.maps.LatLng(-20.21664672710243, -70.15616208314896)];
[Q,Q,Q,Q]
>p1= new google.maps.Polygon({paths: coords,editable: true });
Kh<br>
>all_overlays.push(p1);
2
>all_overlays;
[Object, Kh]
```

Then my new shape appears like 'Kh' , not like Object, then it doesn't have overlay or type properties, I'm wondering about how create a shape like the first one, created through D.M.
in order to attach to it a event listener like the another ones...

I need do that in order to can modify the loaded ones with the DM..

Thanks

Comment: what exactly are  you trying to achieve? Create a copy of the last shape and draw it on the map?

Answer (score -2):

You are using overlaycomplete so you have to dig a little deeper.

maybe try:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function(e) {
        all_overlays.push(e.overlay);
        if (e.overlay.type != "marker") {
        drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null);
        var newShape = e.overlay;
        newShape.type = e.overlay.type;
        google.maps.event.addListener(newShape, 'click', function() {
          setSelection(newShape);
        });
        setSelection(newShape);
      }
    });
```